# object tag causes IE to crash

Tags: java, html, deployment, applet

i have got a Problem with a java applet which i am using on a website. The applet itself worked until the 18th of Mai i guess. Somehow my Page simply crashes, whenever i open it. Neither the java console does open, nor the website does load complete.

on the bottom half of the screen a message pops up -> `an add on for this website failed to run`.
With this message i thought, it might be a probleme on my site, and i started checking if there was any option beeing disabled in the security options for the Internet Explorer. 
I did set the option to the lowest level, but the `crash` continued to happen.

After doing some more reasearch, i found out that my current method, to access the applet, might cause some problems with the IE. i am accessing the Plugin with `type="application/x-java-applet"`.

This method was working for a long time and did not cause any problems. But somehow it is causing problems now and and based on [this](https://eyeasme.com/Shayne/XHTML/appletObject.html) side i did write a statement for the object tag.

The Object Tag written by me:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
   <object type="application/x-java-applet" width="1" height="1" id="jsap" name="jsap">       
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
    <object type="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0016-0000-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA" width="1" height="1" id="jsap" name="jsap">       
<!--<![endif]-->
      <param name="archive" value="save_applet.jar,ojdbc6.jar"> </param>
      <param name="code" value="save_Applet.class"> </param>
      <param name="scriptable" value="true">
   </object>
```

The applet itself, has just one method. This method opens a JFilechoser, to be able to have access to the user System. The applet is signed and working in Chrome and Firefox.
But somehow this implementation does cause problems with the IE. This problem occured like a week ago and it was working before.

Someone has any idea, what can cause my website to crash after i tried to load the applet?

Technical details:

OS -> Windows 7 x64

JRE -> Version 1.6.043

Applet JDK -> Version 1.6.024

IE -> Version 10.0.9200.16576

Comment: The best way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).

Comment: Tip:   `width="1" height="1"`  Make that `width="300" height="200"` - there may be messages in the applet itself.

Comment: It wont have any effects if i would increase the size, because the side crashes earlier on

Comment: *"It wont have any effects if i would increase the size"*  It sure won't if you don't try it.  Good luck with it.

Comment: ok it does basicly work, but how can i include the applet to the current page. If i am starting the script, it does open the applet in a new page.

Comment: *"how can i include the applet to the current page."*  Is that supposed to make sense to anyone that is not looking over your shoulder at the screen containing the HTML?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense. The applet itself should be hidden and not visible to the user. By clicking a "download" button, it does access a method inside the applet which does open a jfilechooser in a seperate container. This gives me access to the users Filesystem. 

By now i am using dtjava instead of deployjava, because as i noticed, deployJava uses document.write, which automaticly gives me a new page. With dtjava i am able to include it to my side, so i can use it as a "background enginge"